# Python item sort

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
my_list=raw_input('Please enter a list of items (seperated by comma): ')
my_list=my_list.split()
my_list.sort()

print "List statistics: "
print ""

for x in set(my_list):
    z=my_list.count(x)

if z>1:
    print x, "is repeated", z, "times."
else:
    print x, "is repeated", z, "time."
```

The output only prints one of the items in the list.  I need to sort the list (dog, cat, bird, dog, dog) to count how many items are in the list, such as:

bird is repeated 1 time.
cat is repeated 1 time.
dog is repeated 3 times.

The problem is that it only outputs 1 item:

bird is repeated 1 time.

Comment: Why are you asking this twice? [Python List Sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833681/python-list-sorting)

Comment: You might want to look at the collections.Counter object.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your test for `z` *inside* the loop:

```
for x in sorted(set(my_list)):
    z=my_list.count(x)

    if z>1:
        print x, "is repeated", z, "times."
    else:
        print x, "is repeated", z, "time."
```

or, simplified a little:

```
for word in sorted(set(my_list)):
    count = my_list.count(word)
    print "{} is repeated {} time{}.".format(word, count, 's' if count > 1 else '')
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'dog', 'dog']
>>> for word in sorted(set(my_list)):
...     count = my_list.count(word)
...     print "{} is repeated {} time{}.".format(word, count, 's' if count > 1 else '')
... 
bird is repeated 1 time.
cat is repeated 1 time.
dog is repeated 3 times.
```

You could also use a [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the counting for you, it has a `.most_common()` method to return results sorted on frequency:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> for word, count in Counter(my_list).most_common():
...     print "{} is repeated {} time{}.".format(word, count, 's' if count > 1 else '')
... 
dog is repeated 3 times.
bird is repeated 1 time.
cat is repeated 1 time.
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Although I am still having issues.  It is now not sorting the list alphabetically and when it prints if there is more than one item it repeats, i.e. (dog, cat, bird, dog, dog): dog is repeated 3 times. cat is repeated 1 time. bird is repeated 1 time. dog is repeated 3 times. dog is repeated 3 times. THANK YOU!

Comment: Sir, that is fantastic!  Thank you so much with your help it has really helped me to better understand what I am doing!